# If every point is a Lebesgue point of $f$, does $f$ satisfy the intermediate value property?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a locally integrable measurable function.

We say $f$ satisfies the *intermediate value property* if given any $a, b\in \mathbb R$ with $a < b$, whenever $u \in \mathbb R$ is such that $\min(f(a), f(b)) \leq u \leq \max(f(a), f(b))$, there exists some $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x) = u$.

**Question:** Suppose every point of $\mathbb R$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$. Does it follow that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value property?

*Note: We use the “strong” definition of Lebesgue point, given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $F(x)=\int_a^x f(x)dx$ (for some fixed $a$), then $x$ being a Lebesgue point of $f$ yields $F'(x)=f(x)$; and the derivatives enjoy the intermediate value property by Darboux theorem.

Comment: Ah, that’s a nice theorem.

Comment: Is the converse true?  If $F'(x) = f(x)$ everywhere, then every point is a Lebesgue point of $f$ ?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: how about something standard, like $F(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$? Its derivative $f$ is bounded and discontinuous at a single point, so is Riemann integrable. Fundamental theorem of calculus tells us then $F(x)  = \int_0^x f(y) ~dy$ for any $x$ (so $F$ **is** the primitive of $f$). But $0$ is not a Lebesgue point of $f$, as $|\cos(1/x)|$ has non-zero mean near $x = 0$.

Comment: SO: (every point is Lebesgue point for $f$)$\Longrightarrow$($F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$)$\Longrightarrow$(intermediate value property for $f$) ... but none of these can be reversed.